# table rescaling and subcaption package

Tags: tables, scaling, tabularx, subcaption

I am placing tables side-by-side using the `subcaption` package in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \large
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
        {%
            \sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
            \begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=1.2(2)]S[table-format=1.2(2)]S[table-format=2.2(2)]S[table-format=2.2(2)]}
                \toprule
                  & {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
                \midrule
                A & 0.09(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96  \\
                B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
                C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
        }
        \caption{}
    \end{subtable}%
    \hspace{0.02\textwidth}%
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \large
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
        {%
            \sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
            \begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=1.2(2)]S[table-format=1.2(2)]S[table-format=2.2(2)]S[table-format=2.2(2)]}
                \toprule
                  & {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
                \midrule
                A & 0.09(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96  \\
                B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
                C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
        }%
        \caption{}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

In a related post, one of the comments was that using `\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}` was bad style, since it leads to inconsistent font sizes. The suggestion was to use the `tabularx` package instead. Thus I left out the `resizebox` command and replaced the calls
to `\begin{tabular}{...}` with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{...}`.
However, now the tables are no longer rescaled to match the `0.48\textwidth` of the subtable. What am I missing? It's strange, since using `\textwidth` in the `resizebox` command correctly picks up on the size of the subtable.

EDIT: I should have noted that in actual fact my table is bigger, but with the same number of columns. Incorporating mico's answer, I get overfull hbox errors.
The problem is I can't make the page much wider due to the need for a large inner margin. This is where the resizebox command came in handy, although it isn't the right way to go. Here is an edited example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,subcaption}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose margins here

\begin{document}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\begin{table}
    \centering
     \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=1.2(2)]
                                     S[table-format=1.2(2)]
                                     S[table-format=2.2(2)]
                                     S[table-format=2.2(2)]@{}}
            \toprule
            &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Error Quantiles}\\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
            &  {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
            \midrule
                   A  & 0.17(1) & 0.25(3) & 0.33(2) & 0.43(2)\\
                   B  & 0.09(1) & 0.12(1) & 0.17(2) & 0.26(5)\\
                   C  & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1) & 0.11(1) & 0.16(1)\\
              \\
                   A & 0.17(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96 \\ % 1e7
                   B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
                   C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\
              \\
                   A & 0.37(6) & 0.73(15) & 1.66(63) & {201}\\ % 1e5
                   B & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1)  & 0.15(2)  &  15.50(33)\\
                   C & 0.06(0) & 0.09(1)  & 0.12(1)  &   0.20(2)\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}%
        \caption{}
     \end{subtable}%
     \hspace*{\fill}%
     \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=1.2(2)]
                                     S[table-format=1.2(2)]
                                     S[table-format=2.2(2)]
                                     S[table-format=2.2(2)]@{}}
            \toprule
            &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Error Quantiles}\\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
            &  {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
            \midrule
                   A  & 0.17(1) & 0.25(3) & 0.33(2) & 0.43(2)\\
                   B  & 0.09(1) & 0.12(1) & 0.17(2) & 0.26(5)\\
                   C  & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1) & 0.11(1) & 0.16(1)\\
              \\
                   A & 0.17(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96 \\ % 1e7
                   B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
                   C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\
              \\
                   A & 0.37(6) & 0.73(15) & 1.66(63) & {201}\\ % 1e5
                   B & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1)  & 0.15(2)  &  15.50(33)\\
                   C & 0.06(0) & 0.09(1)  & 0.12(1)  &   0.20(2)\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}%
        \caption{}
     \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Mico's answer gives a good solution but for `tabularx` you need to specify which columns may stretch, using `X` column type. Also `1\textwidth` is the same as `\textwidth`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could (i) use the `tabular*` instead of the `tabular` (or `tabularx`) environment, (ii) set the width of the `tabular*` to `\linewidth`, and (iii) use the (admittedly complicated-looking) expression `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` to make LaTeX expand the intercolumn white space so that the contents of the table take up the full available width. (Unless instructed to do something else, LaTeX inserts intercolumn whitespace in the amount of `2\tabcolsep` between columns in a `tabular...` environment.)

Separately, I'd also get rid of the `\large` font size directive, use `@{}` to get rid of the extra whitespace at the left and right margins of the tables, not use `\centering` and instead use `\hspace*{\fill}` to separate the two subtables, and make a few other changes here and there to streamline the setup and look of the tables.

---

**Addendum**, posted after receiving information that the OP uses a fairly narrow text block: It's still possible to use the `tabular*` environment, but with two modifications relative to the code I posted originally (now deleted): (i) reduce the value of the `\tabcolsep` parameter from the default value of `6pt` to `1pt` and let LaTeX then insert `\fill` for extra separation, and (ii) change the font size to `\small` (which is `1pt` less than the default font size).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,subcaption}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}  % LaTeX default is 6pt
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,
    detect-inline-weight=math,
    table-format=1.2(2)}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small % reduce font size by 1pt
     \begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
     \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l 
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}} SS
        S[table-format=2.2(2)]
        S[table-format=2.2(2)]@{}}
          \toprule
          \phantom{Var.} &  
          \multicolumn{4}{c}{Error Quantiles}\\
          \cmidrule{2-5}
          &  {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
          \midrule
          A  & 0.17(1) & 0.25(3) & 0.33(2) & 0.43(2)\\
          B  & 0.09(1) & 0.12(1) & 0.17(2) & 0.26(5)\\
          C  & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1) & 0.11(1) & 0.16(1)\\[1ex]
          A & 0.17(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96 \\ % 1e7
          B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
          C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\[1ex]
          A & 0.37(6) & 0.73(15) & 1.66(63) & {201}\\ % 1e5
          B & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1)  & 0.15(2)  &  15.50(33)\\
          C & 0.06(0) & 0.09(1)  & 0.12(1)  &   0.20(2)\\
          \bottomrule
     \end{tabular*}%
     \caption{}
     \end{subtable}%
     \hspace*{\fill}%
     \begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
     \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l 
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}} SS
        S[table-format=2.2(2)]
        S[table-format=2.2(2)]@{}}
          \toprule
          \phantom{Var.}
          &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Error Quantiles}\\
          \cmidrule{2-5}
          &  {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
          \midrule
          A  & 0.17(1) & 0.25(3) & 0.33(2) & 0.43(2)\\
          B  & 0.09(1) & 0.12(1) & 0.17(2) & 0.26(5)\\
          C  & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1) & 0.11(1) & 0.16(1)\\[1ex]
          A & 0.17(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96 \\ % 1e7
          B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
          C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\[1ex]
          A & 0.37(6) & 0.73(15) & 1.66(63) & {201}\\ % 1e5
          B & 0.07(1) & 0.09(1)  & 0.15(2)  &  15.50(33)\\
          C & 0.06(0) & 0.09(1)  & 0.12(1)  &   0.20(2)\\
          \bottomrule
     \end{tabular*}%
     \caption{}
     \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Second Addendum*: In case you feel that this setup (with font size `\small`, 10% smaller than the "normal" font size) doesn't provide enough whitespace between the columns, you could use `\footnotesize` (20% smaller than the "normal" font size):

[image]

Comment: `\centering` can still be used in order to ensure a zero parindent.

Comment: @egreg - Isn't `\parindent` already set to `0` inside a `table` environment?

Comment: Yes, it is; but other classes might not follow the standard ones in this respect.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a much cleaner solution. However, in actual fact my tables are larger, although with the same number of columns. I have amended the question accordingly. Now I get overfull hbox errors, e.g. the table isn't scaling down to 0.48\textwidth...

Comment: @user1753262 - Could you give an indication of the actual value of `\textwidth` -- the width of the page minus the margins -- of your document?

Comment: @Mico: Adding \the\textwidth into the example prints 345.0pt.

Comment: @Patrick - So you're using the LaTeX default value for `\textwidth` for your document? Please confirm.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I've not changed anything, I just ran the example as is.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for all your help, I've accepted your answer. However, having to reduce the column spacing to the point where entries are almost touching, I'm wondering whether resizing the original doesn't actually look better, although it's not strictly correct...

Comment: @Mico Another thing: Isn't the default value of tabcolsep "6pt"?

Comment: @Patrick - You're right: the default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`; I had it confused with the default value of `\arraycolsep`, which is 5pt. Please note that I've provided a second addendum to show how the table might look if one uses `\footnotesize` instead of `\small`. Obviously, most of the information provided by a table is contained in the numbers; IMHO, it's better to keep the numbers as large as possible and sacrifice intercolumn whitespace. Of course, there's no single "correct" way to design and implement a table, and much will depend on other design aspects of your document.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Many thanks for applying these code fixes! (restorations?)

Comment: @Mico -- except they pollute the current active page, and there are still on the order of 7000 more to go ...  sigh.

Answer (score 1):

`tabularx` can still be used. For me it is straight forward than `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,subcaption,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose margins here
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X%
       S[table-format=1.2(2)]
       S[table-format=1.2(2)]
       S[table-format=2.2(2)]
       S[table-format=2.2(2)]@{}}
    \toprule
    Stuff & {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
    \midrule
    A & 0.09(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96  \\
    B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
    C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    \caption{First subtable}
    \end{subtable}%
    \hspace*{\fill}%  % fill up space between the two subtables
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X%
       S[table-format=1.2(2)]
       S[table-format=1.2(2)]
       S[table-format=2.2(2)]
       S[table-format=2.2(2)]@{}}
     \toprule
     Stuff & {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {95\%}\\
     \midrule
     A & 0.09(83) & 0.26(83) & 0.38(83) &  0.96  \\
     B & 0.10(1)  & 0.16(1)  & 0.22(2)  &  0.41(8)\\
     C & 0.08(1)  & 0.12(1)  & 0.19(3)  &  0.52(23)\\
     \bottomrule
     \end{tabularx}%
     \caption{Second subtable}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Overall table caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That puts all the variability in the first column, which is OK here as the line is fairly full but if the line was wide compared to the table data the first column would look a long way off.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. I just wanted to show that in this particular example, `tabularx` can work.