# subtable alignment

Tags: tables, subcaption

I am struggling to align two tables using the `subcaption` package. I have seen [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117911/table-rescaling-and-subcaption-package) to this question that rely on `tabular*` but my tables are produced by a stats software that convert regression output into `tabular` and I want to avoid messing around with them.

The basic flavor of the tables is this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Table}
  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{subtable 1}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% 
    {
      \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
      \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
      \toprule
                          &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A}               &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group B}              \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
                          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Control}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Treatment}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Control}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Treatment}\\
      \midrule
      Condition          &      a        &      b        &      c        &      d\\
                          &      (a)         &      (b)         &      (c)         &      (d)         \\
      Constant (No condition)            &      e&      f&      g&      h\\
                          &      (e)         &      (f)         &      (g)         &      (h)         \\
      \midrule
      Observations        &         N         &         N         &         N         &         N         \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors clustered at the group level.}\\
      \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
      \end{tabular}
    }}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{subtable 2}
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% 
    {
      \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
      \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
      \toprule
                          &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A}               &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group B}              \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
                          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Control}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Treatment}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Control}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Treatment}\\
      \midrule
      Condition          &      a        &      b        &      c        &      d\\
                          &      (a)         &      (b)         &      (c)         &      (d)         \\
      Constant (No condition)            &      e&      f&      g&      h\\
                          &      (e)         &      (f)         &      (g)         &      (h)         \\
      \midrule
      Observations        &         N         &         N         &         N         &         N         \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors clustered at the group level.}\\
      \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
      \end{tabular}
    }}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

When I try to introduce horizontal space (e.g. using `\hspace*{\fill}`) and change the space allocated for each subtable (e.g. `{0.45\linewidth}`) I get an overlapping monstrosity.

This was a bit simpler with the `subfig` package, but I have been told that `subcaption` is now the way to go.

Comment: Put a `%` (comment) symbol immediately after the first instance of `\end{subtable}`.

Comment: Could you please make your example code compilable? Please also reconsider your usage of `resizebox` as this will lead to inconsistent (and in your case most likely also very small) font sizes.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the `subtable` environments, each of width `0.5\linewidth`, currently don't seem to want to be placed side by side is that you've written `\end{subtable}` rather than `\end{subtable}%`. The lack of a `%` (comment) character after the first `\end{subtable}` statement means that a bit of whitespace gets inserted which, in turn, pushes the second `subtable` to the next row.

Your code also suffers from an abundance of pointless, but highly clutter-y, `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrapper statements in colums 2 thru 5. Since the column types of all four data columns is `c`, the wrappers do *absolutely nothing*. Get rid of them.

I would also get rid of (or, at least, comment out) the three `\centering` statements: They, too, *do nothing* -- except create code clutter.

In order to keep the `\resizebox` statements from miniaturizing their arguments excessively, do think long and hard about making the columns -- and especially the header columns -- less wide. E.g., don't place `Constant (No condition)` all on one line. You will get far more pleasing results if you place `(No condition)` on the next line. Other ways of reducing unneeded horizontal expanse (which has to be sized down via `\resizebox`) are (a) get rid of the whitespace adding on either end of the `tabular` environments and (b) reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`, the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace.

Implementing these suggestions, and setting the widths of the `subtable` environments to `0.485\linewidth` (and inserting an `\hfill` instruction), one obtains the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabs,subcaption,graphicx}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
%\centering
\caption{Table}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.485\linewidth}
    %\centering
    \caption{subtable 1}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% 
      \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{c} @{}}
      \toprule
      &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A} 
      &\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Group B}\\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
      & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\
      &Control&Treatment&Control&Treatment\\
      \midrule
      Condition        & a & b & c & d\\
                       & (a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
      \addlinespace
      Constant         & e & f & g & h\\
      \ \ [No condition] & (e) & (f) & (g) & (h) \\
      \midrule
      Observations        & N & N & N & N \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Standard errors clustered at the group level.}\\
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
      \end{tabular}%
   }%
  \end{subtable}%
  \hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.485\linewidth}
    %\centering
    \caption{subtable 2}
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% 
      \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{c} @{}}
      \toprule
      &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A}
      &\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Group B} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
      & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\
      &Control&Treatment&Control&Treatment\\
      \midrule
      Condition        & a & b & c & d\\
                       & (a) & (b) & (c) & (d) \\
      \addlinespace
      Constant         & e & f & g & h\\
      \ \ [No condition] & (e) & (f) & (g) & (h) \\
      \midrule
      Observations        & N & N & N & N \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Standard errors clustered at the group level.}\\
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```